# Exporting results to XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I am trying to create an XML file from a SQL query.
The out put should look like the image below

[image]

Where the tag `BranchID` appears again as `SubParentBranchID` if there are more than one `SubBranchID` associated with `BranchID`. In the image below `BranchID` 94 has two `SubBranchID` 63 and 64.

I've manged this SQL query

```
SELECT
a.[heading_id] as BranchID,
c.[name] as BranchName,
a.[business_id] as SubBranchID, 
a.[heading_id] as SubParentBranchID,
b.[name] as SubBranchName
   FROM [BUSINESSHEADINGLINK] as a
   join [BUSINESS] as b on a.business_id = b.business_id
   join [HEADING] as c on   a.heading_id = c.heading_id 
FOR XML PATH ('Branch'), ROOT('BranchInfo')
```

This gives me the following XML

[image]

Here you can see that neither do i have the tag `<SubBranches>` nor `<SubBranch>`. Also i do not have `<SubParentBranchID>`. The XML file should be like:

[image]

Can anyone help me with the SQL code?

Also i would like to save it on `C:/temp` after execution.

Comment: Try using `ELEMENTS` e.g. `FOR XML PATH ('Branch'), ROOT('BranchInfo'), ELEMENTS` to see you get the desired output.

Comment: I did that but no use

Comment: @Kin and itsAftab: `ELEMENTS` is not the issue here. The issue is producing a multi-level structure as opposed to the default flat structure. And that can only be done by using the two methods I mention in **Part 1** of my answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Part 1: Proper XML Struture**

In order to get anything other than a flat XML layout, you need to use either `FOR XML EXPLICIT` mode, or nested `FOR XML AUTO` queries.  Please see the following MSDN sections for complete details, including examples:

- [Use EXPLICIT Mode with FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx)
- [Use Nested FOR XML Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188276.aspx)

Also, you do not need to generate the `<SubParentBranchID>` element as it is entirely superfluous. One of the nice things about XML is being able to get the parent node from your current location :).

**Part 2: Exporting to a File**

This can be done rather easily with a simple SQLCLR function to save the contents of a variable (or query) into a text file.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = false, IsPrecise = true)]
public static SqlString SaveXmlToFile([SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)] SqlString FilePath,
    SqlXml XmlData)
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(FilePath.Value, XmlData.Value, Encoding.Unicode);
    }
    catch (Exception __Exception)
    {
        return __Exception.Message;
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

And there is no need to do any `NULL` checking of the input parameters via `.IsNull()` since I am using the `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` option:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SaveXmlToFile](@FilePath NVARCHAR(4000), @XmlData XML)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER,
     RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [SomeAssemblyName].[FileUtils].[SaveXmlToFile];
```

Then you can use like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Output XML;

SET @Output = (
   SELECT ...
   FOR XML ...;
);

DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @ErrorMessage = dbo.SaveXmlToFile(N'path/to/file.xml', @Output);
```

A few easy steps to get the above SQLCLR function working (and pretty much any Assembly you create that needs `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE`):

1. The assembly needs to be signed. In Visual Studio, go to Project Properties -> SQLCLR tab -> Signing... button.
2. "CLR Integration" needs to be enabled:

   ```sql
   EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
   RECONFIGURE;
   ```
3. Create an [Asymmetric Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174430.aspx) in `[master]` from the DLL:

   ```sql
   USE [master];
   CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [KeyName]
   FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'Path\to\SomeAssemblyName.dll';
   ```
4. Create a Login `[master]` from the DLL:

   ```sql
   CREATE LOGIN [SomeLoginName]
   FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [KeyName];
   ```
5. Grant the Key-based Login the appropriate permission:

   ```sql
   GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO [SomeLoginName];
   ```

Please notice how none of those steps was to turn the database property of `TRUSTWORTHY` to `ON`!!!

---

An alternate means of getting this SQLCLR function without doing any coding, compiling, creating of Asymmetric Keys or Logins, etc, is to get a pre-done library that you just install. The [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com) library contains several File System functions and bypasses all of the steps shown above. Please note that I am the author of SQL#, and while there is a Free version, the File System functions are only available in the Full version.

Comment: that is too complicated

Comment: What exactly is too complicated? There are two parts here. You don't have much choice about Part 1 if you want to produce multi-level XML natively in T-SQL. For Part 2, that could be made _much_ easier by simply installing a pre-done SQLCLR function. And I do sell a package that contains such a function (and over 250 others) called [SQL#](http://SQLsharp.com/). There is a Free version, but the File System functions are only in the Full version.

Answer (score 3):

If your structure is only two levels deep you can use one nested `for xml` query to build the sub branch part something like this.

```
select H.heading_id as 'BranchID',
       H.name as 'BranchName',
       (
       select B.business_id as 'SubBranchID',
              H.heading_id as 'SubParentBrachID',
              B.name as 'SubBranchName'
       from dbo.BUSINESS as B
         inner join dbo.BUSINESSHEADINGLINK as L
           on B.business_id = L.business_id
       where L.heading_id = H.heading_id
       for xml path('SubBranch'), root('SubBranches'), type
       )
from dbo.HEADING as H
for xml path('Branch'), root('BranchInfo'), type;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78c3b/1)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion..though when i try to save it as XML file on local disk using `queryout (C:\temp\test.xml)` i get an error: Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'

Comment: so i managed to save it but the file is all in one line and without breaks..how do i insert breaks after every node?