# Grant user from my database to execute xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I'm working with SQL Server 2016 and I need to let an user from `MyDatabase` to execute `xp_cmdshell`. I do the following:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO myUser
GO
```

`myUser` is an user from `MyDatabase` and when I run the above code, logged as `sa`, I get the following error:

> Permissions on server scoped catalog views or system stored procedures
>   or extended stored procedures can be granted only when the current
>   database is master.

Do I need to add the user to `master` database? I don't think it is safe.

I need this because I want to write a text file from a stored procedure. I have found the following article, http://www.nigelrivett.net/WriteTextFile.html, saying that I can write a text file using:

```
You will need to create the data to be output as in dynamic sql statements
The first command here creates or overwrites the file - the rest append to the file.
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo hello > c:\file.txt'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo appended data >> c:\file.txt'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo more data >> c:\file.txt'
```

I ask this because my stored procedure will generate a large string (nvarchar(max)) json and when I try to write it down with C# I don't get anything: neither the file or an exception. I've thought to write the json string inside the stored procedure (if I can).

The stored procedure ends correctly, I have checked in the debugger that I get something into the output parameter json (I know it because Visual Studio sets that there is not enough memory to show its contents), the `File.WriteAllText` is run because I have a breakpoint on it, and also, the path is absolute. But maybe, there is something that I ignore and I have to double check everything again.

Comment: Simply adding a user to master isn't unsafe since the user will have only the public permissions they already had via the guest user. However, granting execute permissions on xp_cmdshell is a security concern because the non-sysadmin user can then execute any ad-hoc OS command on the database server, limited only by the xp_cmdshell proxy account permissions. I suggest you specify why you need to do this in your question as there may be a more secure solution.

Comment: @DanGuzman I have added more details about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I suggest you wrap the code that executes xp_cmdshell in a stored proc in your user database and sign it with a certificate that has the needed permissions. That way, users are limited to the proc and can't execute ad-hoc xp_cmdshell commands. [See this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4984c4fa-177d-44c9-8094-8cbd5bc79728/execute-xpcmdshell-as-context-of-a-sysadmin-requires-xpcmdshellproxyaccount-credential-to?forum=sqlsecurity) for an example, except in this case do not add the certificate login to the sysadmin role.

Comment: +1 for Dan Guzman. It's exactly what I would do. Doing it in a proc and giving the right to the user to execute the stored proc is far more secure!

Comment: Why does this have to be a stored procedure? Why can't you generate your output from Powershell, which can easily write to the file system without any of this hokey xp_cmdshell risk. In fact, you could create the procedure that produces the output, and have Powershell simply call the procedure and write to a file. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Vans: what exactly do you need to write out to this text file? Using `echo > filename.txt` is somewhat limited in terms of length and probably characters, etc. Is this simple US English alphanumeric characters or do you have various code pages or Unicode text to save? The default DOS code page for US English is 437, which is not an exact match to 1252, which is what the Latin1_General Collations use.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky `echo > filename.txt` is only an example. I have a stored procedure that outputs a json and, sometimes, that json is very large. In C# code I will write it down to a file, so I've thought to write it to a file directly into the stored procedure.

Comment: @VansFannel Well, as far as I can tell via testing, the max length of a command to pass to `xp_cmdshell` is 8000 characters (i.e. `VARCHAR(8000)`). It does not seem to take `VARCHAR(MAX)`. However, you can do this rather easily via SQLCLR. Please update the question with the requirement for writing out large JSON documents.

Comment: Why not just continue writing it to a file in C#?

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I have updated the question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just asking to evaluate another possibilities. Maybe I will try to write it down with C# but the problem is that I don't know what is the problem: I don't get the file when I use `File.WriteAllText` neither an exception.

Comment: @VansFannel Thanks. You might want to be clearer about what is not working. How are you getting the value from the stored procedure? result set column or output parameter? can you confirm that you get anything back at all, prior to attempting to write out to a file? You might need to post code (again, in a different question) because it sounds like you have it set up to swallow the exception(s). But if you try to create a file, then it either exists, or you have an exception somewhere, or that line never ran.

Comment: @VansFannel Are you 100% certain that the file doesn't get created? Are you using a relative or absolute path for the filename? If relative, are you sure you checked the correct directory? Try using an absolute path. If you used an absolute path and the file isn't there, then that line of code never ran or the exception is getting swallowed somehow.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I have updated the question again with more details.

Comment: @VansFannel This really should be a separate question at this point. What you are not getting a value back or the file created is completely different than how to securely use `xp_cmdshell`. You should open a new question for help with debugging your app code. I'm sure it's something simple that is being overlooked. For now, why not set the .NET variable that you put the JSON output parameter into to a specific value rather than the output parameter value, just to prove that you can create a file from a string variable containing "a". Try to narrow down what you are debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you wrap the code that executes xp_cmdshell in a stored proc in your user database and sign it with a certificate that has the needed permissions. That way, users are limited to the user stored procedure and can't execute ad-hoc xp_cmdshell commands. OS permissions are also limited to the proxy account for non-sysadmin role members. This certificate technique is detailed in [Erland Sommarskog's Packaging Permissions in Stored Procedures article](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html).

Below is an example script.

```
-- Enable xp_cmdshell and create proxy account
USE master;
EXEC sp_configure 'show',1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1;
RECONFIGURE; 
EXEC dbo.sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'YourDomain\YourProxyAccount', 'YourPr0xy@accountPassw0rd';
GO

-- Create certificate in master.
CREATE CERTIFICATE xp_cmdshell_cert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'All you need is love'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'For xp_cmdshell privileges',
   START_DATE = '20020101', EXPIRY_DATE = '20300101';
GO

-- Create a login for the certificate.
CREATE LOGIN xp_cmdshell_cert_login FROM CERTIFICATE xp_cmdshell_cert;
CREATE USER xp_cmdshell_cert_login;
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.xp_cmdshell TO xp_cmdshell_cert_login;
GO

-- Copy cert to user database
DECLARE @cert_id int = cert_id('xp_cmdshell_cert')
DECLARE @public_key  varbinary(MAX) = certencoded(@cert_id),
        @private_key varbinary(MAX) =
           certprivatekey(@cert_id,
              'All you need is love',
              'All you need is love')

SELECT @cert_id, @public_key, @private_key

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) =
      'CREATE CERTIFICATE xp_cmdshell_cert
       FROM  BINARY = ' + convert(varchar(MAX), @public_key, 1) + '
       WITH PRIVATE KEY (BINARY = ' +
          convert(varchar(MAX), @private_key, 1) + ',
          DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''All you need is love'',
          ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ''All you need is love'')'

EXEC YourUserDatabase.sys.sp_executesql @sql;

ALTER CERTIFICATE xp_cmdshell_cert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
GO

USE YourUserDatabase;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.CreateFile
AS
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'echo hello > c:\file.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'echo appended data >> c:\file.txt';
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'echo more data >> c:\file.txt';
GO
ADD SIGNATURE TO dbo.CreateFile BY CERTIFICATE xp_cmdshell_cert
   WITH PASSWORD = 'All you need is love';
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.CreateFile TO YourUserOrRole;
GO
ALTER CERTIFICATE xp_cmdshell_cert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the aspect of the question dealing with permissions related to executing `xp_cmdshell`, I agree with (and upvoted) [Dan's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/201785/30859). However, given the new information regarding the reason for this request (i.e. writing out large JSON documents), security for `xp_cmdshell` becomes a moot point since `xp_cmdshell` can only handle a maximum of 8000 `VARCHAR` characters (less if using a Double-Byte Character Set and certain characters therein, but that's probably not the case here, just something to be aware of). Also, I seem to recall that certain characters did not work so well on the command line and couldn't easily be escaped (but currently can't find any).

So perhaps it would be best to accept Dan's answer for this question (since it is correct for the question as stated), and then open a new question about how to best export large JSON documents, and I can transfer this answer over to that question.

---

This operation can be handled rather easily via SQLCLR using the `File` class.

Please see the following answer of mine, also here on DBA.SE, that includes some code examples for doing this type of thing:

[Exporting results to XML](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116828/30859)

Also, for anyone not wanting to mess with the coding, deployment, etc: there is a **File_Write** function available in the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/) library (which I wrote) that handles this and even allows for passing in the desired encoding so that the file can be saved as UTF-8 with a Byte Order Mark (BOM), for example. Please note that this function is only available in the Full version, not in the Free version. This is a fairly simple function to create, but best to have options.